# How to plot only the current frame with animation.FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Generating the data:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

coords = dict()
for j in range(10):
    x=np.random.uniform(0.0, 5.0,2);
    y=np.random.uniform(0.0, 5.0,2);
    vx=np.random.uniform(-1,1,2);
    vy=np.random.uniform(-1,1,2);
    coords[j]= {'x': x, 'y':y, 'vx':vx, 'vy':vy}
```

The plotting part:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)


ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)

def update_quiver(frameIdx):
    global coords
    frame = coords[frameIdx]
    X = frame['x']
    Y = frame['y']
    U = frame['vx']
    V = frame['vy']
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='k', units='inches')

    Q.set_UVC(U,V)
    return Q,
```

And then plotting:

```
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(),
                               interval=50, blit=False, frames=max(coords.keys()))
anim
```

[image]

How can I visualize only the current location of the particles and not the whole trajectory?

When I try:

```
def update_quiver(frameIdx):
    global coords
    fig.clf()
    ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
    ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    frame = coords[frameIdx]
    X = frame['x']
    Y = frame['y']
    U = frame['vx']
    V = frame['vy']
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='k', units='inches')


    Q.set_UVC(U,V)
    return Q,
```

It doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to remove the quiver I commented about might look as follows:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

coords = dict()
for j in range(10):
    x=np.random.uniform(0.0, 5.0,2);
    y=np.random.uniform(0.0, 5.0,2);
    vx=np.random.uniform(-1,1,2);
    vy=np.random.uniform(-1,1,2);
    coords[j]= {'x': x, 'y':y, 'vx':vx, 'vy':vy}

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.set_xlim(-1, 6)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 6)

Q = ax.quiver(1,1,1,1, alpha=0)

def update_quiver(frameIdx):
    global coords, Q
    frame = coords[frameIdx]
    X = frame['x']
    Y = frame['y']
    U = frame['vx']
    V = frame['vy']
    Q.remove()
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='k', units='inches')
    return Q,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(),
                               interval=500, blit=False, frames=max(coords.keys()))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try clearing the figure in `update_quiver`:

```
fig.clf()
```

EDIT: this code works on my computer:

```
def update_quiver(frameIdx):
    frame = coords[frameIdx]

    plt.cla()
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 7)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 7)

    X = frame['x']
    Y = frame['y']
    U = frame['vx']
    V = frame['vy']
    Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V, pivot='mid', color='k', units='inches')

    Q.set_UVC(U,V)
    return Q,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_quiver, fargs=(),interval=500, blit=True,frames=np.arange(len(coords)))
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's what I actually tried to do, but it didn't work. The whole animation ended up as a white screen.

Comment: I tried and got it working with `plt.cla()` in `update_quiver` as  ImportanceOfBeingErnes mentioned, however you have to set ylim and xlim after clearing axes again.

Comment: it doesn't added it to my questions

Comment: I have posted the code that works correctly on my computer and draws two arrows in each frame.